# Active Directory Users and Computers delegated user cannot create user accounts

Tags: active-directory

Windows Server 2016 Active Directory under an
Organizational Unit (OU), I created a user which was delegated control to be able to create, delete and manage users, and passwords.

I logged in with this user account, but the options is missing, for example NEW TAB where one can create new users, OU's, printers etc.

If I supply administrator credentials, still
signed in as this same user, I can create and/or delete everything as usual.

Comment: You need to provide screen shots of the OU permissions for that user account where the account was delegated these permissions.  Which is also the same OU where you are right-clicking to select New User.

Comment: Dear Sir Greg i will certainly do that i am sorry was caught up in trying to figure out what is the cause of the issue i forgot to provide some informational images,i will do that later today ! Have a great day